# How can i remove (none ) in myresult:

Tags: python, nonetype

How do I remove that NONE at the end

```
import textwrap

def wrap(string, max_width):
    l = len(string)
    sp = 0
    diff = 4
    case = True
    while case:
    print(string[sp:diff],end="\n")
    sp = sp + 4
    diff = diff + 4
    if diff>l:
        print(string[sp:])
        case = False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    string, max_width = input(), int(input())
    result = wrap(string, max_width)
    print(result)
    # cannot modify this part of code
```

Expected:

```
ABCD
EFGH
IJKL
MNOP
QRST
UVWX
YZ

MY RESULT:
ABCD
EFGH
IJKL
MNOP
QRST
UVWX
YZ
NONE
```

Comment: Please paste your code here instead of image.

Comment: In addition to pasting code in your question, you can go to [this site](https://repl.it/) and create a runnable example of your code.

Comment: Please include your code inline (not as image attachment). Also provide input to your program and then results. Learn [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: at end check if sp > string.length and break

Comment: @Vaibhav I've used case for that.

Comment: you are checking endpointer not starting pointer as per above code

Comment: @Vaibhav still I've None at the end, I want to get rid of that. I think it have something to do with that print statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your wrap function is printing your results

since there is no return from the function you are getting None

instead of this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
string, max_width = input(), int(input())
result = wrap(string, max_width)
print(result)
```

do this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
string, max_width = input(), int(input())
wrap(string, max_width)
# result = wrap(string, max_width)
# print(result)
```

your wrap function is not returning anything so no need to store it's output

Comment: sorry sir, forgot to mention HackeRank doesn't allow to edit that  if __name section    I was thinking that maybe something I can replace my print statement with in wrap function

Comment: can you please give the link to the question here OR try returning "" OR return the list instead of printing it OR return a multiline string

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/text-wrap/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&isFullScreen=false

Comment: use this  return (textwrap.fill(string,max_width)).....The fill() convenience function works similar to textwrap.wrap except it returns the data joined into a single, newline-separated string. This function wraps the input single paragraph in text, and returns a single string containing the wrapped paragraph.

Comment: That Worked. Thanks Sir

Comment: I am glad that it helped, happy programming. :)